# `mmap` and `sendfile` interoperability

Tags: linux, file, memory-mapped-files, sendfile

I have a file, which is opened by `open`:

```
fd = open("ABC", O_RDWR | O_NOATIME);
```

The file is memory-mapped by `mmap`:

```
ptr = (uint8_t*)mmap(nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Everything works OK. Then at some point I call `sendfile` to copy another file to the `fd` descriptor:

```
bytesCopied = sendfile(fd, fd_src, nullptr, size);
```

(I'm simplifying a little here - I have a loop, error checks etc.)

It looks like the file content, which is accessible via the `fd` descriptor, is **not** what is in the another file - it's messed up.

My question is - how am I supposed to say Linux to update its memory buffers to sync with external file changes? The `msync` isn't suitable here, I need to sync in opposite direction.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: I suppose you *could* evict everything using `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` ... I'm not sure what effect that has on *other* caching.